# Woocommerce Js elements are not loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I really hope someone can help me with this, it is driving me mad and frustrating me. I have installed WooCommerce on an off-line test site on a default theme (TwentyThirteen) and it works and looks great.

When applying it to a theme I have developed however,it works fine. All the woocommerce style has loaded but the woocommerce javascript file is not loaded. I had used some other woocommerce plugin and its js file also not loaded. But when I used TwentyThirteen theme all works fine and all the woocommerce styles and javascript files are loaded but when applying to my theme only style file is loaded

I've tried all the instructions on the WooCommerce website to integrate it to my theme (both methods of either using a catch all page, or adding hooks), and all of this still results.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: I think its not a server fault but error in code which I am unable to figure out. Hoping to get help from someone

Comment: "I have installed WooCommerce on an off-line test site on a default theme (TwentyThirteen) and it works and looks great." - configuration/administration of a professional server. Regardless, this question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Yes, twenty thirteen theme works fine when my theme doesn't load only js file. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Are you sure in default theme there is noJS error? use console tab in chrome browser to detect any error.

Comment: There is no JS error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had solved the problem. Because of deregister the wordpress jquery and registering the jquery by another handle I think it doesn't load the woocommerce js script. Like

```
function theme_script(){
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

  wp_register_script('jqueryreal',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/jquery.js',array(),'4.2');
   wp_enqueue_script('jqueryreal');


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_script');
```

When I remove the above function from the functions.php ,then problem is solved. All the js element are loaded and works fine as I want .